# How do i pass values from longitude and latitude into latlng and then into an arraylist in another activity?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, geofencing

[My Basic UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbNtQ.png)

I have a very basic UI where i want the user to able to save the latitude and longitute of the location they want to set a geofence to. What I'm wondering is how do i get  both latitude and longitude and convert it into latlng and then pass the value into my map activity into an array list.Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

ApprovedAreas = new ArrayList<>();

```
    ApprovedAreas.add(new LatLng(37.4205940 ,-122.044 ));
    ApprovedAreas.add(new LatLng(37.459979 ,-122.138770 ));
    ApprovedAreas.add(new LatLng(37.4475940 ,-122.9044 ));
```

Comment: if you want to pass data between activities you should use `Bundle` check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

In this activity

```
    ArrayList<LatLng> areas  =  new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    savezone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    areas.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText().toString()),Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText().toString()));
                }
            }); 


gotomap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent i = new Intent(currentactivity.this, mapactivity.class);
                 i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("areas", areas);
startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

In mapactivity

```
ArrayList<LatLng> areas  =  getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("areas");
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering however on the line (new LatLng(latitude.getText().toString(),longitude.getText().toString()); i had an error it said Latlong (double , double) in latlng cannot be applied to (java,langstring,javalangstring)

Comment: use Double.parseDouble to convert string to double

Comment: how do i do that, so sorry i'm still learning android thanks for the help btw